# NeuralNetwork can't train XOR (but OR works just fine)

Tags: java, machine-learning

## Summary

Heyy I'm new to machine learning and I have tried to code my own neural network. As a simple task I chose to train the OR gate "behavior", which worked just fine. Than I wanted to try the XOR gate and there comes the problem. The neural network doesn't seem to train correctly, because the output, even after training, doesn't match the expected output.

I have tried to backtrack the problem, but I wasn't successful, maybe because im not experienced in this field.
As a "guide" to see how to code the backpropagation I have used a tutorial on YT by Finn Eggers. The playlist is named: NN - fully connected tutorial.

Expected: 0.0, 0.0 -> 0.0 | 0.0, 1.0 -> 1.0 | 1.0, 0.0 -> 1.0 | 1.0, 1.0 -> 0.0|.

Actual rounded: 0.0, 0.0 -> 0.29 | 0.0, 1.0 -> 0.64 | 1.0, 0.0 -> 0.53 | 1.0, 1.0 -> 0.59|.

The last result is not really what was expected (or acceptable, because I can't just look if its over 0.5 or under and than say 1 or 0).

ty for you help.

## Complete Code

```
public class NeuralNetwork 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        NeuralNetwork nn = new NeuralNetwork(new int[]{2,2,1});
        //training data for the nn
        double[] in1 = new double[]{0.0, 0.0};
        double[] in2 = new double[]{0.0, 1.0};
        double[] in3 = new double[]{1.0, 0.0};
        double[] in4 = new double[]{1.0, 1.0};
        
        double[] out1 = new double[]{0.0};
        double[] out2 = new double[]{1.0};
        double[] out3 = new double[]{1.0};
        double[] out4 = new double[]{0.0};
        
        int set = 0;
        //trains the nn with data from above
        for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            if(set == 0)
            {
                nn.train(in1, out1, 0.3);
            }
            else if(set == 1)
            {
                nn.train(in2, out2, 0.3);
            }
            else if(set == 2)
            {
                nn.train(in3, out3, 0.3);
            }
            else
            {
                nn.train(in4, out4, 0.3);
            }
            set = (set + 1) % 4;
        }
        
        //test runs the data to see what output the nn is producing
        nn.run(in1);
        nn.run(in2);
        nn.run(in3);
        nn.run(in4);
    }
    
    public int[] layers;
    //input layer
    public Neuron[] input;
    //output layer
    public Neuron[] output;
    //neural network
    public Neuron[][] nn;
    
    public NeuralNetwork(int[] layers)
    {
        this.layers = layers;
        
        //creates the neural network
        this.nn = new Neuron[layers.length][];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.nn.length; i++)
        {
            this.nn[i] = new Neuron[layers[i]];
            for(int k = 0; k < layers[i]; k++)
            {
                //creates a neruon and gives it an input if its not in the input layer of the nn
                this.nn[i][k] = (i == 0)? new Neuron(): new Neuron(this.nn[i - 1]);
            }
        }
        
        //sets the input layer
        this.input = this.nn[0];
        //sets the output layer
        this.output = this.nn[this.nn.length - 1];
    }
    
    //calculates the output of the nn but doesnt train the nn
    public void run(double[] in)
    {
        calculate(in);
        double[] result = new double[this.output.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.output.length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = this.output[i].output;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
    
    //trains the nn
    public void train(double[] in, double[] out, double rate)
    {
        calculate(in);
        backPropagate(out);
        updateWeights(rate);
    }
    
    //calculates the output of the nn
    public void calculate(double[] in)
    {
        //sets the input of the neural network
        for(int i = 0; i < in.length; i++)
        {
            this.nn[0][i].output = in[i];
        }
        
        //runs the neural network
        for(int i = 1; i < this.nn.length; i++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < this.nn[i].length; k++)
            {
                this.nn[i][k].calculateOutput();
            }
        }
    }
    
    //backpropagates the error (atleast it should)
    public void backPropagate(double[] target)
    {
        //calculates the error of the output layer
        for(int i = 0; i < this.output.length; i++)
        {
            this.output[i].error = (this.output[i].output - target[i]) * this.output[i].derivative;
        }
        //calculates the error of the hidden layer
        for(int i = this.nn.length - 2; i > 0; i--)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < this.nn[i].length; k++)
            {
                double sum = 0;
                for(int a = 0; a < this.nn[i + 1].length; a++)
                {
                    sum += this.nn[i + 1][a].weights[k] * this.nn[i + 1][a].error;
                }
                this.nn[i][k].error = sum * this.nn[i][k].derivative;
            }
        }
    }
    
    //updates the weights of the hidden layer(s) and the output layer
    public void updateWeights(double rate)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < this.nn.length; i++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < this.nn[i].length; k++)
            {
                double delta = -rate * this.nn[i][k].error;
                
                this.nn[i][k].bias += delta;
                
                for(int a = 0; a < this.nn[i - 1].length; a++)
                {
                    this.nn[i][k].weights[a] += delta * this.nn[i - 1][a].output;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Neuron 
{
    public double error;
    public double output;
    public double bias;
    public double derivative;
    public double[] weights;
    public Neuron[] inputs;
    
    //constructor for neurons of the hidden / output layer
    public Neuron(Neuron[] inputs)
    {
        //sets the inputs of the neuron
        this.inputs = inputs;
        //creates random weights
        this.weights = new double[inputs.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.weights.length; i++)
        {
            this.weights[i] = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble();
        }
        //sets a random bias
        this.bias = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble();
    }
    
    //empty constructor (for the input layer)
    public Neuron()
    {
        
    }
    
    public void calculateOutput()
    {
        appyActivationFunction(calculateSum());
        calculateDerivitive();
    }
    
    public double calculateSum()
    {
        double sum = this.bias;
        for(int i = 0; i < this.inputs.length; i++)
        {
            sum += this.weights[i] * this.inputs[i].output;
        }
        return sum;
    }
    
    public void appyActivationFunction(double in)
    {
        //applys the sigmoid function
        this.output = 1.0 / (1.0 + Math.exp(-in));
    }
    
    //calculates the derivative
    public void calculateDerivitive()
    {
        this.derivative = this.output * (1.0 - this.output);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done further testing and when I set the number of epochs (here 5.000) to 20.000 I the results where more in the right direction. At >30.000 the results were satisfying. Lession learned (I think) -> test the structure of the NN and the training time depending on what your data will be

Comment: Please do not use the comments space for such additional info - edit & update your post instead.

Comment: generally you can look at your loss. you should have seen that it hasnt converged yet. You had 2 options at that point: A) increase the learning rate but this might generally lead to the loss converging at an error that is to high to be accepted (but very likely not in this case). B) using more iterations